# Adding a DOM element to a constructor function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

if I have a constructor function and want to plug in a DOM element how do I do this? I figure I need to convert it to a string but I'm not sure & I can't quite figure out how to convert it. Thank you.

```
function MyFunk(domElementVar,domElementString) {

this.domeElementVar = document.getElementById(this.domeElementString);


};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current function is a constructor that accepts two arguments: an element and a string. This means you would call it as `new MyFunk(document.getElementById(...), "...")`.

What you want instead is a constructor that only accepts a string, and finds the element itself. Note that:

- For arguments, do not use `this.`. They are variables available inside the function.
- For properties on the object being constructed, do use `this.`.

So:

```
function MyFunk(domElementString) {
  this.domeElementVar = document.getElementById(domeElementString);
}
```

Comment: Ok, I actually already knew this, (but thanks for the explanation..which I didn't know).I was thinking along the wrong lines toward the real problem I am trying to solve. I reworded my problem into a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13560218/cant-pass-a-dom-element-to-a-constructor-function-in-javascript-when-trying-to