# Can't pass a DOM element to a constructor function in Javascript when trying to abstract section of WebAudio API xhr request

Tags: javascript, dom, web-audio-api

My problem is this. When I add an argument to the **audioBoing function** below and then place the same argument in the **getElementById** string, the function doesn't work. I get an error that says **uncaught type error, cannot call method 'AddEventListener' of null**

The function below works fine. I rewrote the function below it to reflect what I'm trying to do. Ultimately I am trying to abstract a good portion of the function so I can just plug in arguments and run it without having to rewrite it each time for each sound it stores / launches.

```
var playAudioFileOneDrumOneBig = function () {
var source = context.createBufferSource();
source.buffer = savedBufferOne;
source.connect(delay.input);
delay.connect(convolver.input);
convolver.connect(context.destination);
source.noteOn(0); // Play sound immediately
};




function audioBoing()  
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('get', 'audio/F.mp3', true);
xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
xhr.onload = function () {
        context.decodeAudioData(xhr.response,
             function(incomingBuffer1) {
                 savedBufferOne = incomingBuffer1;
                 var noteOneDrumOneBig = document.getElementById("noteOneDrumOneBig"); 
                 noteOneDrumOneBig.addEventListener("click", playAudioFileOneDrumOneBig , false);
             }
        );
};
xhr.send();
};

audioBoing();
```

**ReWritten non-working**

```
function audioBoing(yay) {      //added yay

this.yay=yay;                 // defined yay

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
xhr.open('get', 'audio/F.mp3', true);
xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
xhr.onload = function () {
        context.decodeAudioData(xhr.response,
             function(incomingBuffer1) {                  
                 savedBufferOne = incomingBuffer1;    
                 var noteOneDrumOneBig = document.getElementById(yay);           //passed yay
                 noteOneDrumOneBig.addEventListener("click", playAudioFileOneDrumOneBig , false);   //error happens here
             }
        );
};
xhr.send();
};

audioBoing(noteOneDrumOneBig);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't quote the string you passed to `audioBoing`

```
audioBoing("noteOneDrumOneBig");
```